# Multiple Submit Buttons - html express node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a like/dislike system. So essentially, there are two buttons on the html side.

```
<form method="post" name="ratings">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="like">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="dislike">
</form>
```

However, I only know how to do a single function. How can I seperate it? I'm working in node js.

So, like the first line of code looks like this:

```
router.post('/test/*', function (req, res) {
```

Like what would the if statement look like in javascript? or do I have to change the html code and do something with onclick? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be more semantic to use two separate forms.

Comment: it would be better to make two routes

Comment: post with ajax, and call two routes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. You can get the name from req.body.vote and then use that value to do whatever.

```
var inputValue = req.body.vote;

if (inputValue == "like") {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use ajax, somelike this..

Buttons:

```
 <button name="btnLike" value="like" onclick="like()">
 <button name="btnDislike" value="dislike" onclick="dislike()">
```

JS:

```
function like(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/like",
        type: "POST",
        data: {like: 'yes'}, //send this to server
        success: function(returned) {
             console.log(returnet); // here can get the return of route
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}

function dislike(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/dislike",
        type: "POST",
        data: {dislike: 'yes'}, //send this to server
        success: function(returned) {
             console.log(returnet); // here can get the return of route
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Routes:

```
router.post('/like', function (req, res) {
}

router.post('/dislike', function (req, res) {
}
```

Comment: This is a nice and clean way but you don't need the like or dislike = yes as its already apparent from the endpoint. You can send any other useful data if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use formaction

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/like" name="vote"></button>
<button type="submit" formaction="/dislike" name="vote"></button>
```

Below is the link

[Parsing Form With Multiple Submits](https://medium.com/@ShiyaLuo/parsing-forms-with-multiple-submit-buttons-in-node-js-with-express-4-4e5cf46d0bd7)